# Getting logcat errors using httpclient on Android

Tags: android

I've been getting this error and I can't seem to find the solution.

```
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at com.samplefillform.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-02 06:08:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(7306):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I'm not even sure if this code will work if this error will be remove, I've been finding a way to do this for 3 days now and still no luck.

What this app does is the user enters a name and when the button is press the name is send to a remote server form right now that's my localhost using xampp. here my source code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.samplefillform;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button send;
    EditText name;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFName);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);

        final String sname = name.getText().toString();

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HttpClient postClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String postReq = "http://10.0.2.2/formcode.php";
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(postReq);
                List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("element_8_1", sname));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity postEntity = null;
                try {
                    postEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                request.setEntity(postEntity);

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = postClient.execute(request);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/etFName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bSend"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etLName"
        android:text="Send"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samplefillform"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and finally the php file that handles the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>App Test Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./data/form_6/css/view.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="images/top.png" alt="" />
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>App Test Form</a></h1>
        <form id="form_6" class="digitalfuture"  method="post" action="#main_body">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>App Test Form</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description">Name <span id="required_8" class="required">*</span></label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_1" name= "element_8_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value="" />
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_2" name= "element_8_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value="" />
            <label>Last</label>
        </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_8"><small>Please tell us your name</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_9" >
        <label class="description">Phone Number <span id="required_9" class="required">*</span></label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_1" name="element_9_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_9_1">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_2" name="element_9_2" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_9_2">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_9_3" name="element_9_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_9_3">####</label>
        </span>
        <p class="guidelines" id="guide_9"><small>Please tell us your phone number</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_10" >
        <label class="description">Alternate Phone Number </label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_1" name="element_10_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_10_1">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_2" name="element_10_2" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="element_10_2">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_10_3" name="element_10_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_10_3">####</label>
        </span>
        <p class="guidelines" id="guide_10"><small>Please tell us an alternate phone number to contact you at</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_11" >
        <label class="description" for="element_11">Email <span id="required_11" class="required">*</span></label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_11" name="element_11" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="your@email.com" /> 
        </div> 
        </li>

    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="images/bottom.png" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html&ei=fq1qUP2wBcSzrAeA-oHQAg&usg=AFQjCNEvDLBzaeCg8fLhaGHPBER4o27tuw&sig2=MCqtlSzjaT4z8Dd6hPR2sQ) since you are acceising webServices from your Main Ui thread.

To avoid this you have to use Async Tasks or threads,

```
 send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {

                HttpClient postClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String postReq = "http://10.0.2.2/formcode.php";
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(postReq);
                List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("element_8_1", sname));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity postEntity = null;
                try {
                    postEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                request.setEntity(postEntity);

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = postClient.execute(request);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();


        });
```

Comment: well the error is now gone, but when i view the formcode.php there's no change, the input field is still empty

Comment: everything seems to check out

Answer (score 1):

Its exactly what is says...
In Android 3 and up you cannot make network calls on the main/UI thread.
You'll need to open new Thread for it. In your ClickListener put:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }).start();
```

Put all the network code inside the `run()` function.

Answer (score 1):

It's forbidden to perform a networking operation on application main thread. You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this : [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html)